# Data sent through jQuery/AJAX PUT request is retrieved as null in controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a problem with one of my AJAX api functions:

```
var baseURL = "http://localhost:8208/api/";

function updateMultipleQuestions(questionsPrototype, callback) {
    var url = baseURL + "Questions?isMultiple=true";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: questionsPrototype,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        statuscode: {
            200: function (output) {
                callback(output);
            },
            201: function (output) {
                callback(output);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The questionsPrototype is an object of the type MultiQuestion which is an array of Questions:

```
function Question()
{
    this.ID = 0;
    this.Index = 0;
    this.ImageURL = "imgurl_?";
    this.Title = "";
    this.QuestionText = "";
    this.SectionID = 0;
    this.CommentLength = 0;
    this.Required = false;
    this.NumberOfAllowedAnswers = 0;
    this.NumberOfAllowedCharacters = 63;
    this.OptionChoices = [];
    this.QuestionType = 0;
}

function MultiQuestions()
{
    this.Questions = [];
}
```

This data is supposed to be sent to the controller:

```
// PUT: api/Questions?isMultiple=true
[ResponseType(typeof(MultiQuestionActivityModel))]
public IHttpActionResult PutQuestion([FromUri] bool isMultiple, MultiQuestionActivityModel Questions)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    using (var uow = new UnitOfWorkFactory().Create())
    {
        var QuestionActivity = new QuestionActivity(uow);
        if (QuestionActivity.MultiQuestionSave(Questions) > 0)
        {
            return Ok(Questions);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle this
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not save questions")); ;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when I call the api function updateMultipleQuestions the correct data is sent into the function but from the ajax call to the controller the data has become null (MultiQuestionActivityModel Questions)(Checked in debugging mode).

I have tested the url in Postman with the same data and the call works as it should which makes me believe that the problem lies in the AJAX call, possibly one of the header parameters might be used wrong?

I am fairly new at this and might have overlooked something. 
Thanks beforehand
/Janmumrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Ajax call you saying that the data type your sending is json but you're not sending json. Maybe you could try using `JSON.stringify()` in Data:

Comment: I can swear that I've tried that multiple times before but I might have done that while testing around with different header parameters. Seems to work like a charm, thanks!